# Multi-select in Orchid view template

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, orchid

I have a custom field in Orchid (12.2), and I am using a `view()` template with a custom HTML table to display input for comments and a select (multi-select) for comment categories. How can I include Orchid fields/inputs in this custom HTML view? I want to use Orchid's multi-select field instead of including jQuery.

Comment: It's always a good practice to include a minimal, reproducible example when asking questions on StackOverflow. This makes it easier for others to understand the problem and provide a solution.